# How to get NUnit Assert.Pass() tests to be reported as passing in SpecFlow+ Runner

Tags: specflow, nunit-3.0, specrun

I have a suite of regression tests that I am trying to convert from the NUnit runner to use the SpecFlow+ Runner.  I've gotten them more or less running, with this major gotcha:

Many of my rests end with an Nunit Assert.Pass().  When I run those tests in SpecFlow runner, it reports them as test failures.

What can I do to get those reported as passing?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include: a) SpecFlow nuget package version; b) SpecFlow+ Runner nuget package version; c) Nuget package version for NUnit. I suspect `Assert.Pass()` is throwing an exception, and SpecFlow+ Runner interprets *any* exception as a failure. Maybe you can configure SpecFlow to ignore this exception type, or simply remove those lines of code. They are unnecessary. No exceptions thrown == test passed to SpecFlow.

Comment: The `Assert.Pass(...)` method throws a `SuccessException`. Maybe try to detect that in an `[AfterScenario]` hook?